# Pandas: Error while searching asterisk in dataframe. Eg: busiest_hosts['host'].str.contains('***.botol.dk')

Tags: python, r, pandas, data-science, text-analysis

Below is what my dataframe looks like, as you would see one of my dataframe column is URL and other is timestamp count. When I am running this code: `busiest_hosts[busiest_hosts['host'].str.contains('***.novo.dk')==True]` I get an error: `error: nothing to repeat at position 0`. Which I think is because the first element of my URL is `*`. It seems like a python bug (my python version is 3.x). I would really appreciate if anyone could help me in resolving this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`contains` assumes the string is a regex expression and interprets the `*` as a command to repeat the prior character or expression.  You want to escape the `*`.  And while you're at it, escape the `.` as well.

```
busiest_hosts[busiest_hosts['host'].str.contains('\*{3}\.novo\.dk')==True]
```

***demo***

```
busiest_hosts = pd.DataFrame(dict(host=['***.novo.dk', '007.thegap.com'], timestamp=[16, 45]))

print(busiest_hosts)

             host  timestamp
0     ***.novo.dk         16
1  007.thegap.com         45
```

---

```
busiest_hosts[busiest_hosts['host'].str.contains('\*{3}\.novo\.dk')==True]

          host  timestamp
0  ***.novo.dk         16
```

Or as OP pointed out to me ;-), just turn regex off `regex=False`

```
busiest_hosts[busiest_hosts['host'].str.contains('***.novo.dk', regex=False)==True]
```

Comment: Oh I see. But since I need to check all URLS in my dataframe. Can I do `str.contains(host, regex=False)`

Comment: @JubinSoni Yes!!  Or that.